# April Fools 2015

Tags: support

The question [SharePoint Server 2016 Site Action Menu Left or Right](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137027/sharepoint-server-2016-site-action-menu-left-or-right) was as some of you guessed - an April fools question. You who have 10k rep or more are able to read the now deleted question, and on Tuesday next week I'll present an image here (if someone of the other mods don't beat me to it) of the question, so everyone can read it.

[image]

Hope you liked the prank :-)